# How to Optimize an IPTABLES script?

Tags: linux, iptables

If I could list that which iptables rule has how many matched packets, then I could create a better/faster iptables script that's faster. That rule would be at top/first that has the more packets matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iptables -L -n -v`

See also this article: http://greenmice.info/en/node/127, there are some other tips.

Comment: The link you shared seems to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't spend all that much time worrying about this.  If you have a rule which you know gets hit extremely often (related,established rule for example), you could put that near the top.  But in general I highly doubt that any more optimization will really pay off in any way.